# Connection timed out when running socket client on another network

Tags: java, connection-refused

My problem is that I get the "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" Exception when I run the client on another network (my phones hotspot). It works fine on the same network, I think its a problem with the firewall, but even after enabling Eclipse and disabling firewall for every type of network it still doesn't work.

The Client:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;  
public class MyClient {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try{      
            Socket s=new Socket("192.168.0.36",6666);  
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
            dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
            dout.flush();  
            dout.close();  
            s.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
    }  
}
```

The Server:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
public class MyServer {  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        try{  
            System.out.println("Server Running");
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);  
            Socket s=ss.accept();   
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
            String str=(String)dis.readUTF();  
            System.out.println("message= "+str);  
            ss.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
    }  
}
```

Comment: And the server has the ip `192.168.0.36` ?

Comment: ip keeps changing when you connect to different networks, how do you know the Ip is 192.168.0.36? you can find the ip address of your server and then connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your global IP address instead of your local IP address. Currently, "192.168.0.36" is on your local network. If you wish to access it from a different network, you need to use your global IP address. There are some tools out there that mean you do not need to remember your global IP address (or give it out), for example [NO-IP](https://www.noip.com/). [MY-IP](https://www.myip.com/) tells you your global IP address also.

On a side note, you may also need to port forward port 6666 on your router. Only look into this is the above doesn't work on its own. You may need to do both. Information on port forwarding is easily available on Google depending on the manufacturer of your router.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed the IP address but it still doesn't work. I don't know if I want to port forward. I heard it can be dangerous.

Comment: @WinnieThePooh port forwarding can be dangerous, but only if you turn off your firewall. For your uses, it should be fine. I have done this many times myself before. If you use No-IP, then you don't have to give out your IP address if you want other people to connect. Port forwarding will be the only way you can get this to work if just changing your IP address doesn't work.